# Populating the values of a column based on multiple conditions to a new column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Say I have a following data frame,

```
df.head()
col1    col2    col3    start   end     gs
chr1    HAS     GEN     11869   14409   DDX
chr1    HAS     TRANS   11869   14409   NaN
chr1    HAS     EX      11869   12227   NaN
chr1    HAS     GEN     12613   12721   FXBZ
chr1    HAS     EX      13221   14409   NaN
chr1    HAS     EX      12010   12057   NaN
```

Now, I need to add a new column based on two conditions and value must be used from one column.

For instance, the conditions are.

- if `col3` is equal to `GEN` or `EX`. Then add a new column `col7` with the value from column `gs`.
- The value from `gs` must be always the value when the `col3` is equal to `GEN`. That is never the `NaNs`.

In the end, I am aiming to have my data frame as following,

```
col1    col2  col3   start   end     gs     col7
chr1    HAS   GEN    11869   14409   DDX    DDX
chr1    HAS   EX     11869   12227   NaN    DDX
chr1    HAS   TRANS  11869   14409   no
chr1    HAS   GEN    12613   12721   FXBZ   FXBZ
chr1    HAS   EX     13221   14409   NaN    FXBZ
chr1    HAS   EX     12010   12057   NaN    FXBZ
```

I tried using `lambda` :

```
df.apply(
    lambda row: row['gs'] if (row['col3'] =="EX" and row['gs'] !=NaN) else "no",
    axis=1)
```

However, I am not able to populate the values from the `gs` column to the new column. It sets `NaN` values. which I do not want.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and forward filling missing values in column `gs`:

```
df['col7'] = np.where(df['col3'].isin(['GEN','EX']), df['gs'].ffill(), 'no')
print (df)
   col1 col2   col3  start    end    gs  col7
0  chr1  HAS    GEN  11869  14409   DDX   DDX
1  chr1  HAS     EX  11869  14409   NaN   DDX
2  chr1  HAS  TRANS  11869  12227   NaN    no
3  chr1  HAS    GEN  12613  12721  FXBZ  FXBZ
4  chr1  HAS     EX  13221  14409   NaN  FXBZ
5  chr1  HAS     EX  12010  12057   NaN  FXBZ
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['gs'].ffill())
0     DDX
1     DDX
2     DDX
3    FXBZ
4    FXBZ
5    FXBZ
Name: gs, dtype: object
```